# How to reference/link XML elements within the document and then parse with python

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I am trying to make sense of XML capabilities and I have a document that creates a map. The map consist of nodes and edges. The "nodes" element describes the available nodes and the "edges" connects the given nodes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <map>
    <nodes>
        <node id="1">
            <x>1</x>
            <y>0</y>
        </node>
        <node id="2">
            <x>0</x>
            <y>1</y>
        </node>
        <node id="3">
            <x>1</x>
            <y>1</y>
        </node>
    </nodes>
    <edges>
        <edge id="1">
            <from>1</from>
            <to>2</to>
        </edge>
        <edge id="2">
            <from>2</from>
            <to>3</to>
        </edge>
        <edge id="3">
            <from>3</from>
            <to>1</to>
        </edge>
    </edges>
</map>
```

In this snippet nodes with IDs 1, 2 and 3 are defined and connected with edges between nodes 1-2, 2-3 and 3-1.

Is there a way to refer to nodes defined within the document instead of just providing their IDs? I have seen one answer suggesting:

```
<edge id="1">
    <from><xpath-ref select="../../../../nodes/node[@id='1']"/></from>
    <to><xpath-ref select="../../../../nodes/node[@id='2']"/></to>
</edge>
```

...but then I cannot parse beyond the xpath-ref point:

```
In [2]: map = xml.dom.minidom.parse('map.xml')
In [3]: xpath.find('./map/edges/edge[@id=1]/from/xpath-ref', map)
Out[3]: [<DOM Element: xpath-ref at 0x1042fdfc8>]
```

In the code above I used [py-dom-xpath](https://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/).

For example I **cannot** do:

```
xpath.find('./map/edges/edge[@id=1]/from/xpath-ref/x', map)
```

or:

```
xpath.find(m.find("./edges/edge[@id='1']/from/xpath-ref").attrib['select'], x)
```

Any python XPath spaghetti eater to help please?
Thank! :)

Comment: Can you explain again in one sentence what you want to select, exactly?

Comment: (because *"Is there a way to refer to nodes defined within the document instead of just providing their IDs"* would be as simple as `//node`)

Comment: i don't understand about python, but xpath `//node[@id=//edge[@id=2]/from]  | //node[@id=//edge[@id=2]/to]` gives you nodes from and to

Comment: Ok, I was probably not that clear. I am trying to
1) create a reference from *edge/from* to *node with id=1*.
2) access it with a simple python xpath as in xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: A reference as in "a string that refers to this node" or as in "a reference to a DOM node object"?

Comment: my comment gives you set of two nodes. is it right?

Comment: @Tomalak My ignorance probably gets in the way of expressing myself. I guess the latter of the options you are stating is more appropriate and more generic.

Comment: Well, I think it's time that you explain what you want to achieve overall. ;)

Comment: @splash58 The xpath you have quoted should do the job, but is it a good practice to link nodes and edges this way:  <edge id="1"><from>1</from><to>2</to></edge>

Comment: @Tomalak I am trying to achieve a clear human/python readable xml. I am worried about the xml good practices as my experience is limited! Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: The XML is pretty clear and readable if you ask me, what do you think that it should look like after you're done?

Comment: @Tomalak it should be understandable that the `<from>1</from>` refers to node with id=1 and it should be easy to get that this node with id=1 has `<x>1</x><y>0</y>` !

Comment: I think that's more of a presentation problem, right? Since every node could be part of any number of edges, there is no point in repeating it in the XML, right? Don't mix up data representation and visual representation, it will lead to no good.